# Implement Fingerprint reading functionality in Hybrid Cordova apps

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

We have implemented an hybrid application. We have a requirement to include Fingerprint reading in our Application. Do we have any cordova plugins to support this functionality. Kindly Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this blog on how to implement the Touch ID authentication with Worklight 6.2.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/touchid_authentication_with_worklight?lang=en